# TPL Dataflow ProducerConsumer Pattern

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Just wrote a sample producer consumer pattern using TPL DataFlow. I have some basic questions here.

1. The consumer is active only after all the items are posted from the producer. Does asynchronous means that both produce and consume tasks can run in parallel.
2. Given a sleep time in consumer to verify if its blocking other data items. It seems to be executing sequentially and not getting any parallelism.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
class AscDataBlocks
{
    public Int64 start;
    public Int64 End;
    //public string ThreadName;
    public void AscBufferProducer(ITargetBlock<Int64> targetAscTransform) 
    // This is using TPL DataBlock producer consumer pattern.
    {
        for (var i = start; i < End; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Postingasc : {0}", i);
            targetAscTransform.Post(i);
        }
    }

    public void ProcessDataBuffer(Int64 ascDataSet)
    {
        if (ascDataSet == 5) 
        // Testing if this will delay all the other data processing
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        else
            Thread.Sleep(500);                
        Console.WriteLine(ascDataSet);
    }

    // Demonstrates the consumption end of the producer and consumer pattern. 
    public async Task<Int64> AscTransConsumerAsync(IReceivableSourceBlock<Int64> source)
    {
        // Initialize a counter to track the number of bytes that are processed. 
        int status = 0;

        // Read from the source buffer until the source buffer has no  
        // available output data. 
        while (await source.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            Int64 data;
            source.TryReceive(out data);
            ProcessDataBuffer(data);//This function processed the data buffer for ascollection and writes the data to the database.
            // Increment the count of bytes received.
            status = 1;
        }
        return status;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AscDataBlocks ascb;
    BufferBlock<Int64> ascbuffer;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Int64> ascProcessingconsumer;
    CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ascb = new AscDataBlocks();
    ascb.start = 1;
    ascb.End = 100;           
    try
    {
        ascbuffer = new BufferBlock<Int64>(new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
            CancellationToken = ct
        });// Initiallize the buffer bloack
        ascProcessingconsumer = ascb.AscTransConsumerAsync(ascbuffer); //Initialize the consumer.
        //Post source data to the dataflow block.
        ascb.AscBufferProducer(ascbuffer);
        ascProcessingconsumer.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //foreach (var v in ex.InnerExceptions)
        //    Console.WriteLine("msg: " + v.Message);                
    }            
}
```

Comment: BTW, C# is not C, you don't have to specify all your locals at the start of the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The consumer is active only after all the items are posted from the producer. Does asynchronous means that both produce and consume tasks can run in parallel.

This happens because you post all your items very quickly, before the consumer has a chance to start. If you added `Thread.Sleep(100)`, you would see that they actually do work in parallel.

> Given a sleep time in consumer to verify if its blocking other data items. It seems to be executing sequentially and not getting any parallelism.

TPL Dataflow is not magic: it won't modify your code to execute in parallel. It's you who calls `AscTransConsumerAsync()` once, so don't be surprised that it actually executes only once.

TDF does support processing in parallel, but you would need to actually let it execute the processing code. To do this, use one of the execution blocks. In your case [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684) seems appropriate.

If you use that, you can then configure the block to execute in parallel by setting [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism). Of course, doing that means you need to ensure that the processing delegate is thread-safe.

With that, `AscTransConsumerAsync()` might now look something like:

```
public async Task<Int64> AscTransConsumerAsync(ISourceBlock<Int64> source)
{
    // counter to track the number of items that are processed
    Int64 count = 0;

    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<Int64>(
        data =>
        {
            ProcessDataBuffer(data);
            // count has to be accessed in a thread-safe manner
            // be careful about using Interlocked,
            // for more complicated computations, locking might be more appropriate
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        },
        // some small constant might be better than Unbounded, depedning on circumstances
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

    source.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    // this assumes source will be completed when done,
    // you need to call ascbuffer.Complete() after AscBufferProducer() for this
    await actionBlock.Completion;

    return count;
}
```